# Read Value of MySQL connection string property 'allowNanAndInf'

Tags: java, mysql, connector-j

MySQL has a connection string flag called `allowNanAndInf`. I have a java webapp with a connection string containing `allowNanAndInf=true`. The `allowNanAndInf` connection string flag tells MySQL to permit `NaN` values in double fields.

I changed the file that should control the connection string and rebooted my server, but MySQL ConnectorJ still will not permit `NaN` values in double fields.

As a debugging step, I would like to printout the current value of `allowNanAndInf` on my datasource. I am using hibernate, but I can't seem to find any documentation about how to printout the current value of a connection string property for a JDBC connection. Any ideas? How can I printout the current value of the `allowNanAndInf` connection string flag for a connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your should debug your datasource connection object, remember that Hibernate receives a connection to deal with, I dont think that Hibernate has any utility to debug datasources, for debugging purposes you should try to use DriverPropertyInfo collection from your Driver class.

Something like this

```
DriverPropertyInfo[] attrs = driver.getPropertyInfo("jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb", props);
```

You can find a great example here

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/GetDriverPropertyInfo.htm

Comment: I've been trying to follow your answer, but I only have Hibernate Session and SessionFactory objects available to my class. I don't actually have the full connection string to instantiate a new connection. The connections are created by either DBCP or C3P0. So to use your answer, I would need to find a way to access the "DriverPropertyInfo[]" from the Hibernate Session or SessionFactory objects and I don't see an appropriate getter on either of them.

Comment: Yes, But You can Get the JDBC Connection Object from Hibernate objects, such as getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
and then session.connection() . You can use that because you're debugging.

Comment: Once you have the connection, then you CAST the connection to the com/mysql/jdbc/Connection which has the property getAllowNanAndInf() which is that you're looking for.

Comment: Ah, I was missing the casting step. Thanks.